# Azure Devps: How to specify Data Factory Parameters for Pipeline and Link Services

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I am trying to build a release pipeline for azure data factory. I have parameterized link service like database with username and server-name. Also, I have specified some pipeline parameters.

In azure devops release pipeline, these parameters do not appear in template parameters list. However link services connection string uses them which cause the deployment to fail.

The SQl connection string format is: Integrated Security=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;Data Source=@{linkedService().SQLDBServer};Initial Catalog=TESTDB;User ID=@{linkedService().SQLDBUserName}

Now, the deployment throws exception for SQLDBServer and SQLDBuserName

My question is that how to I specify/replace pipeline or link-services connection parameters in release pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using arm-template-parameters-definition.json file I can use parameters defined in pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)